# How do I programmatically repeat a key while it is held?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to automatically repeat LButton while it's held down, then stop when it's released, I've ran into a problem where it will continuously repeat itself even while it's not been held down.

Is there any workarounds for this?  I need it to also work on other applications which is why I'm using `GetAsyncKeyState`.

This is what I have so far:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
   Const KeyDownBit As Integer = &H8000
   Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vkey As Integer) As Short
   Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwflags As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal cbuttons As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)
   Private Const mouseclickup = 4
   Private Const mouseclickdown = 2

   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton) And KeyDownBit) = KeyDownBit Then
            mouse_event(mouseclickup, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            Thread.Sleep(100)
            mouse_event(mouseclickdown, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        End If
  End Sub
```

With this code, when I left click, the code will continuously keep clicking automatically even when Lbutton is released, but that's not exactly what i want.  I want it so when I hold LButton, it will then continuously click, then when LButton is released, it will stop clicking.

I have tried using a `BackgroundWorker`, although the same thing happens.

I have also tried having `mouse_event(mouseclickdown, 0, 0, 0, 0)` before `mouse_event(mouseclickup, 0, 0, 0, 0)`, but then it just turns a single click into a double click each time it's pressed down, then stops.

Comment: I don't think you should be using `GetAsyncKeyState`, the documentation states: "Determines whether a key is up or down at the time the function is called, **and whether the key was pressed after a previous call to GetAsyncKeyState**." (emphasis mine).

Comment: Have you tried using `GetKeyState` instead?

Comment: @Dai : The documentation also says: _"If the most significant bit is set, **the key is down**"_, which is what the `KeyDownBit` variable is used to check. The `If`-statement in the timer will only return `True` if the key **is actually down**, so there's no problem about him using `GetAsyncKeyState`.

Comment: The problem here is that your code keeps both clicking and checking `LButton`. It keeps clicking since `LButton` is also triggered every time your `If`-statement executes. The only way I know to avoid this would be to send mouse click window messages to the window located below the mouse. The approach is somewhat advanced though.

Comment: I'll see if I can put together a solution for you when I've got the time.

Comment: You have said both `key` and `button`. Are you talking about the mouse left button, or the left arrow key on the keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason <kbd>LMB</kbd> keeps getting clicked is because you keep sending a new mouse click every time you detect one.

Since `GetAsyncKeyState()` reads the keyboard/mouse input stream you cannot use any method that adds clicks to the stream since everything will get stuck like you are currently experiencing.

In order to eliminate the problem I put together a helper class with a method that will send mouse clicks as ***window messages*** to the window below the click point. By doing so we are now sending mouse clicks directly to the window instead of the keyboard/mouse input stream, meaning that `GetAsyncKeyState()` won't take notice of it.

> **EDIT (2019-08-16)**
>
> The `MouseInputHelper` class has since long been merged with `InputHelper`. The answer has been updated to use the latter instead.
>
> **Download InputHelper from GitHub:**
> https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/releases

Now in your timer you can do:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If InputHelper.Mouse.IsButtonDown(MouseButtons.Left) Then
        InputHelper.WindowMessages.SendMouseClick(MouseButtons.Left, Cursor.Position)
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Joey : So finally we got that solved, eh? :) -- By the way, if I may ask, what happened to your old account?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a crack at it, and make some assumptions.

Assumption 1: if you are interested in the left key <kbd>Left</kbd> being pressed, then **the form has focus**. You can use a flag to keep track of key presses

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim timer As New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf timer_tick, Nothing,
                                            System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite,
                                            System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
    ' keeps track of whether the key is pressed
    Dim lKeyIsPressed As Boolean = False
    ' how fast do you want the action to be performed?
    Dim interval As Integer = 100

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        timer.Change(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite,
                     System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ' enable the timer
        timer.Change(interval, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
    End Sub

    Private Sub timer_tick(state As Object)
        If lKeyIsPressed Then
            ' this is where you will perform your action when the key is pressed
        End If
        timer.Change(interval, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        lKeyIsPressed = (e.KeyCode = Keys.Left)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then lKeyIsPressed = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

Change `interval` to control how quickly you want to perform actions while the key is pressed

Assumption 2: if you are interested in the left mouse button <kbd>LMB</kbd> being pressed, you should add these handlers:

```
Private Sub mouseDownHandler(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    lKeyIsPressed = (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
End Sub

Private Sub mouseUpHandler(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then lKeyIsPressed = False
End Sub
```

But you also want to keep track of the mouse being clicked on child controls i.e. a Label. So add this to Form_Load

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    AddHandler c.MouseDown, AddressOf mouseDownHandler
    AddHandler c.MouseUp, AddressOf mouseUpHandler
Next
```

Lastly, you should dispose any disposable resources when you're done with them

```
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
        timer.Dispose()
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Not to ruin your nice answer, but I believe the OP is someone I've helped before who's now using a new account... And if I remember it correctly he was trying to make a clicker for an external game (thus he's using `GetAsyncKeyState()` to be able to check the LMB state without his app having focus).

Comment: No worries. I figured maybe there was something more to it, but it wasn't specified. This answer could help other people who get to the question because it really wasn't that specific.

Comment: I actually managed to find a solution to the OP's original problem. By sending mouse window messages to the window below the cursor, the clicks are sent directly to the window instead of the mouse/keyboard input stream. Thus, `GetAsyncKeyState()` won't notice a thing.