# How do I disable a key on a GetAsyncKeyState but still be able to get input from it?

Tags: vb.net

So I have this code where if leftclick is pressed down, it activates Timer 1, I am trying to make it so after the getasynckeystate, it disables left click then runs timer 1 but I want it so if I let go of left click, the GetAsyncKeyState still gets input from my left click (detect that I let go of left click) then disable timer 1. How could I achieve this? This is an autoclicker by the way. Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
    Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
        hotkey = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton)
        If CBool(hotkey) = True Then
            Timer1.Start()
        Else
            Timer1.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        hotkey = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton)
        If hotkey = True Then
            **** CANT PUT THE CODE HERE BECAUSE I DONT WANT IT PUBLIC BUT IT BASICALLY PRESSES LEFT CLICK ****
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Exact duplicate: [How do I programmatically repeat a key while it is held?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248323/how-do-i-programmatically-repeat-a-key-while-it-is-held)

Comment: I guess I didn't explain my question clearly, what I meant is after my GetAsyncKeyState, I want it so windows doesn't detect that I still have my left click held down and only detects timer 1 (the autoclicker) and still be able to get the GetAsyncKeyState to stop timer 1 if I let go of my physical left click (in real life), I am going to try the solution you left on that post and see if it helps though.

Comment: Ok so I tried your solution and it somewhat works however, whenever i move my mouse around, my game doesnt get the input from the autoclicker.

Comment: No, I understood what you meant but what you ask _specifically_ is impossible (hence why I used Window Messages as a workaround). -- The code in my answer clicks at the mouse's current position. You would have to replace `Cursor.Position` with the _screen coordinates_ you want to click at.

Comment: FYI `GetAsyncKeyState` is an OS function, so if Windows doesn't detect the physical key then neither will `GetAsyncKeyState`. The only workaround _**is**_ a window message solution.