# Not sure what is causing this

Tags: vb.net

So I have this all inside a timer that runs every 80 ms and for some reason when this function activates, it SOMETIMES get stuck and keeps going even though I'm not holding down left click. I also tried adding a second check (clickdone) but it's still doing it. What's causing it here I think is the delay but I kind of need that delay so if anyone here could help me by adding another check or something that fixes this, it would be appreciated! Here is my code:

```
Sub MyDelay()
    Dim randomlul As New Random
    Dim ezdelay As Integer
    ezdelay = randomlul.Next(private delay, private delay)

    Dim iCount As Integer = 1
    For iCount = 1 To ezdelay
        iCount = iCount + 1
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        hotkey = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton)
        If CBool(hotkey) Then
            If (clickdone = True) Then
                mouse_event(mouse_downclick, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                clickdone = False
                MyDelay()
                clickdone = True
                mouse_event(mouse_upclick, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            End If
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

This is not a duplicate of that post that was linked, I tried that other solution but it messed up my other functions so now I have to make a counting delay which doesnt mess up the other functions but now the problem is that the getasynckeystate keeps looping sometimes

Comment: A loop for a delay is horrible.  Look at [`Threading.Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the first `Sub` should be `Public Sub`.Maybe

Comment: Try calling the mouse click from Me.Buttons

Comment: You really need a [mcve] here. We **need to be able to run your code** and see the same results. Chances are your problem is because you are tying up the UI thread in the loop, but we really need to be sure. Please post a complete example.

Comment: @freefaller sleep freezes the program and I have other timers inside this program that need to run and I've even tried modified sleeps, still messes up the other timers

Comment: @Enigmativity Yeah, I think it is that im tying up the UI thread in the loop... Any fix to that?

Comment: @TGamer Me.Buttons is even worse

Comment: @TGamer Nvm actually, it was the public sub that made it worse

Comment: So what exaclty does the code do?

Comment: @TGamer So, Its pretty much just an autoclicker and it auto clicks when im holding down my left click, but sometimes it just gets stuck in a loop untill I press left click again

Comment: Haven't I already linked you to this? It's still an exact duplicate: [How do I programmatically repeat a key while it is held?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248323/how-do-i-programmatically-repeat-a-key-while-it-is-held)

Comment: @Inzample - Use a timer or use `sync` and have an `await Task.Delay` in your code. You need to free up the UI thread.

Comment: @Inzample - Could you provide a [mcve] please?

Comment: For some reason what you said the program should do looks like what you made it do. But I am unfamiliar with code working sometimes and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it gets stuck is because `GetAsyncKeyState()` reads the virtual mouse and keyboard input stream, not the state of the physical key. Thus the code will keep executing since it notices more clicks in the input stream.

As stated in a [**previous answer of mine**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41253296/3740093) you must send the mouse clicks as window messages instead since they won't get noticed by `GetAsyncKeyState()`.

> ***EDIT (2017-07-31):***
>   I've deprecated my `MouseInputHelper` class and merged it with my regular `InputHelper` class. Rest assured the functionality is still the same.
>
> **Download `InputHelper` from my GitHub repository:**
>   https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/releases

You should be able to use this like:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If InputHelper.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.LButton) Then
        InputHelper.WindowMessages.SendMouseClick(Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left, Cursor.Position, True, True)

        'Do stuff here...

        InputHelper.WindowMessages.SendMouseClick(Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left, Cursor.Position, False, True)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148803/discussion-on-answer-by-visual-vincent-not-sure-what-is-causing-this).